# Set different images for different checkboxes in a QTreeView

Tags: css, qt, qtreeview

I subclassed a QTreeView and I have two columns where there are checkboxes. I would like to set two different images: one for the first column, and another one for the second column. I know I can change the image in the stylesheet with:

```
QTreeView::indicator:checked{
    image: url(:/checked);
}

QTreeView::indicator:unchecked{
    image: url(:/unchecked);
}
```

but it will change all the checkboxes in the tree view. Is there a way to do it with the stylesheets, or do I need to use a delegate?

Comment: Maybe have a look at custom properties... https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets

Comment: @Robert How would you do it with dynamic properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: Stylesheets can't do that (as far as I know). They are a pretty immature feature in Qt, and there seems to be no development on them either.

What you can do:

### Stylesheets

You cannot assign properties to a column or an item and you cannot access the columns by index.

But you can use some of the pseudo-states selectors like `:first`, `:middle` and `:last`:

```
QTreeView::indicator:first:checked{
    background: red;
}
QTreeView::indicator:middle:checked{
    background: blue;
}
QTreeView::indicator:unchecked{
    background: lightgray;
}
```

I used colors instead of images for the sake of simplicity.
Note however, that these pseudo-states are actual currently visible states, so if the user is allowed to reorder columns, the style of the column might change. For example if the user drags one of the `:middle`columns and drops it at the end, the box will not be blue anymore.

### DecorationRole

You can fake it using `Qt::DecorationRole`.

To do so, you have to receive the `mousePressEvent` either by subclassing `QTreeView` or by installing an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter). You can then change the icon (via `Qt::DecorationRole` + `emit dataChanged()`) when the user clicks in the area of the icon.

This does not work with the keyboard of course.

### Custom ItemDelegate

Subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and override `paint()`, just as you suggested.

### Custom Style

If you are creating a heavily styled application, you probably have to create a custom Style sooner or later. Stylesheets just don't support some features.

To do so, subclass [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html), override `drawPrimitive` and handle the drawing if `QStyle::PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck` is passed. You will also receive a `QStyleOptionViewItem` of which has some useful properties like `checkState`, `features` (contains `QStyleOptionViewItem::HasCheckIndicator` if there is a checkbox), and of course `index` so you can determine what kind of checkbox you want to draw.

### Edit: Appendix

#### Example Using a Custom QStyledItemDelegate

```
void MyItemDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    const QWidget *widget = option.widget;
    QStyle *style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();

    QRect checkRect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, &opt, widget);
    drawCheckBox(painter, checkRect, opt.checkState, index);
}

void MyItemDelegate::drawCheckBox(QPainter * painter, const QRect & checkRect, Qt::CheckState checkState, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    if (checkState == Qt::Checked)
    {
        switch (index.column())
        {
            case 0:
                painter->fillRect(checkRect, Qt::red);
                break;
            default:
                painter->fillRect(checkRect, Qt::blue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        painter->fillRect(checkRect, Qt::lightGray);
    }
}
```

This example is quick and easy. Simply paint over the checkbox drawn by QStyledItemDelegate. Requires you to fill the whole box however, otherwise the original will be visible.

You can try to use QStyledItemDelegate to draw anything but the checkbox, and draw the checkbox afterwards, but that is a little harder and will leave you with some minor drawing artifacts if you don't want to spend too much time on it.

#### Example Using a Custom QProxyStyle

```
void MyStyle::drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement pe, const QStyleOption * opt, QPainter * p, const QWidget * w) const
{
    if (pe == QStyle::PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck)
    {
        const QStyleOptionViewItem * o = static_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItem *>(opt);
        drawCheckBox(p, opt->rect, o->checkState, o->index);
        return;
    }
    QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(pe, opt, p, w);
}
```

The `drawCheckBox()` function is the same as in the first example.
As you can see, this way is much simpler, cleaner and has none of the drawbacks. You can apply the style globally, or only for a single widget.

Comment: Good answer so far. I'm using a delegate currently but I'm struggling to see what to use for the checkbox. I know there is `option.checkstate` available, but have no idea how to use it. Could you add an example to your answer?

Comment: I even found a way to do it with a delegate without having to fill the whole checkbox :-). Instead of `QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);`, I used `style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &opt, painter, widget);`. Works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hm... That should still draw the checkbox? And if it doesn't, it should not leave the space for the checkbox

Comment: From Qt's doc, `The primitive element PE_PanelItemViewItem is responsible for painting the background of items` so I'm guessing it's only painting the background of the item in the tree view, not the checkbox.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However you will be missing the text and decoration icon then? Might be fine for your needs of course.